# My links stop working when the box hover is applied

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

Ive tried using z-index to over rule the absolute and relative positioning on the box hovers but it just doesn't work. Any body got any suggestions as to why? The links are there but to the side of the images rather than directly above.

HTML

```
 <div id="container1">
     <a href="firstcoding.html"> <img src="images/blindsided1.jpg"> </a>
     <div class="textbox">
         <p id="title1">First Coding <br> Attempt</br></p>
         <p id="text1"> This brief was my first attempt at designing a website.</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
a:hover {
    z-index: 99;
}
#container1 {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}
.textbox:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
#title1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"bebas";
    font-size:32px;
    word-spacing:2px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#text1 {
    padding-top:40px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"bebas";
    font-size:16px;
    word-spacing:2px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
.textbox {
    width:361px;
    height:362px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    border-radius:300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

Comment: Can you plz post proper HTML snippet???

Comment: `position:absolute` and `float:left` aren't compatible...pick one or the other,

Comment: We can't imagine what this 'blindside' image is you're referring to, please clarify

Comment: Here is a fiddle with some random image http://jsfiddle.net/2x3c8coz/ but I am unsure of what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you attempting to make the hoverable div clickable to the link that the image is pointing at? You can wrap the whole hoverable div in the anchor tag if that's the case.

Comment: Wrapping the a tag around the whole div worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I will post this as the answer so anyone can refer to it anytime in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole hoverable div in the anchor tag, that way you can ensure that the hoverable div is clickable and that it points to the link that the image is referencing.

HTML

```
<div id="container1"> 
    <a href="firstcoding.html"> 
        <img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"> 
        <div class="textbox">
            <p id="title1">First Coding
                <br>Attempt</br>
            </p>
            <p id="text1">
                This brief was my first attempt at designing a website.
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
a:hover {
    z-index: 99;
}
.textbox:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
#title1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"bebas";
    font-size:32px;
    word-spacing:2px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#text1 {
    padding-top:40px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:"bebas";
    font-size:16px;
    word-spacing:2px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
.textbox {
    width:361px;
    height:362px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    border-radius:300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely positioned child is sitting on top of the anchor link so any pointer interaction would fail.

You could use `pointer-events:none` on that child which would allow events to pass through but browser support it not great.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a,
img {
  display: block;
}
#container1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
#container1:hover .textbox {
  opacity: 1;
}
#title1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 32px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#text1 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.textbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <a href="firstcoding.html">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-c-361-362-10.jpg" />
  </a>

  <div class="textbox">
    <p id="title1">First Coding
      <br/>Attempt
    </p>
    <p id="text1">This brief was my first attempt at designing a website.</p>
  </div>
```

You would do better to wrap the div inside the link and re-factor your code as suggested in the comments.